# Flask on uWSGI on Ubuntu 12.10 - version mismatch?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, flask, wsgi, uwsgi

I'm trying to follow this guide to serve my Flask app with uWSGI: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/uwsgi/

However, when I try to run `uwsgi`, I get the following problem:

```
(venv)deniz@lister:~/sites/site-lister$ uwsgi -s /tmp/lister.sock --module flood --callable app
uwsgi: unrecognized option '--module'
getopt_long() error
```

I guess this is a version mismatch, because my version of uwsgi is 1.2.3-debian. But if that's the problem and I'm new to Ubuntu, how would I get a newer version properly installed without manually building everything?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to unstall uwsgi, you can just do:

```
pip uninstall uwsgi
```

Then re-install the latest version:

```
pip install uwsgi
```

Then use this documentation for your flask app with uwsgi:

http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Embed.html

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following docs, I have set up a few Flask sites with it.

http://library.linode.com/web-servers/nginx/python-uwsgi/ubuntu-12.04-precise-pangolin